# Mock Generic Repository with Moq

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq and trying to mock a IDummyRepository which implements IGenericRepository interface, and need to verify a call for the Add method of IGenericRepository. But with the example code below I'm getting a MockException.

If I replace the IGenericRepository in the ServiceDummy for the IDummyRepository the test works, but not in the way I need.

How this can work?

```
[TestClass]
public class DummyServiceSpec
{
    protected DummyService service;
    protected DummyModel model;

    [TestClass]
    public class Work : DummyServiceSpec
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExpectToWork()
        {
            var repositoryMock = new Mock<IDummyRepository>();
            var serviceDummy = new ServiceDummy(repositoryMock.Object);
            var entity = new Dummy { DummyString = "DummyString" };

            serviceDummy.Add(entity);

            repositoryMock.Verify(r => r.Add(It.IsAny<Dummy>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
        }
    }
}

public class ServiceDummy
{
    protected IGenericRepository<Guid, Dummy> dummyRepository;

    public ServiceDummy(IDummyRepository dummyRepository)
    {
        this.dummyRepository = dummyRepository;
    }

    public virtual void Add(Dummy entity)
    {
        this.dummyRepository.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just found the problem, it was a bug in my GenericRepository code.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your code of repository expectations to your Moq setup of the repository. Since the Add() method is a void, there is no result to check but you can make it verifiable to test that it is actually called.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExpectToWork()
{
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IDummyRepository>();
    var serviceDummy = new ServiceDummy(repositoryMock.Object);
    var entity = new Dummy { DummyString = "DummyString" };

    repositoryMock.Setup(i => i.Add(It.IsAny<Dummy>())).Verifiable();

    serviceDummy.Add(entity);
    repositoryMock.Verify();
 }
```